# How to execute some code on particular time on the server..?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

For example I have to execute a code after 10 mins of every entry in database.
Like whenever client add a new row to the database, after 10 mins I have to execute a method.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Create a timer and task for every  DB entry like this.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    public void run()
    {
    //execute the code for every 10 mins
    }
}
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10 * 60 * 1000); // period is  10 mins
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cron` job, `cron` is a time-based job scheduler that allows you to to run code periodically at certain times or dates.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

For eaxmple this runs 'dosomething.sh' every 10 mins.

`*/10 * * * * /home/me/dosomething.sh`

Examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application.

If you are using servlets and jsps only and do not use EJB, clustering etc., just create java.util.Timer and add there task every time you are updating DB. The timer will run task according to the scheduling.

If you are developing more "serious" application you can use Quartz.

Other possible approach is using delayed JMS messages. See [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/sending-delayed-jms-messages) for details.

And the next, the most complicated approach is using JCA. You can create JCA component that has "legal" access to Application Server's thread poll and timer.

Comment: It also depends whether the delayed processing must be guaranteed or not. If the system must guarantee it's processed, the timer must either be persistent, or the system must record which entry was processed by the job, so that it can be restarted in the worst case (e.g. a crash).

Comment: Thanks for the reply..!!
Yes I am using JSP and Servlets only. I want to elaborate my question now, kindly help me out as I am new to this thing.
What I exactly want to do is, at every entry in database I also want to record the time at which entry was done in database(let say 16:00).
Then after 10 mins(at 16:10) I want to execute some code.
How to do this specifically ?
attach some code link if possible.
Thanks a ton ..!!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how accurate your '10 minutes after user enters a row' needs to be. The key thing will be to bind the 'task' you want to execute to the trigger data. Thus you'll probably want to add some sort of transaction id to the data. You can then add a time stamp to this transaction data and then have a scheduled event that checks periodically (say every 15 seconds) and if it finds any transaction that has just passed its 10 minute mark, execute its next step.